# Ubuntu Phone BQ E5: File manager broken, Unable to install Dekko

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch, bq

yesterday I've acquired an Ubuntu phone and after several hours of blunder with it, I've got the following problems:

- I can't open the file manager: After clicking the "open button" it instantly closes again
- I can't import my contacts from the SIM, eventhough I've read that the OS should be able to right now.
- Can't install Dekko mail client: It reads something like this in the description: "If the installation fails, update your phone"
- Thus I'm getting the feeling that my phone doesn't update correctly. Eventhough it says "last updated 5/8/16" I never saw it updating the phone itself, just the apps and it says "system is up-to-date"

Can anyone out there offer any help? I'm very much inclined to just send the phone back...

Comment: 1- What version are you on? (System settings -> About) Ubuntu 15.04 (OTA-10.1) is the latest as far as I know.
2- What did you try to import contacts? I see the option 'Import from SIM' in the settings for the contacts app.

Comment: Yes "import contacts" SHOULD be in the contacts app, but in Version 14.10 (r2) it isn't, unfortunately. But it is very good to know that the updating process obviously isn't working! Any idea how to force an update?

Answer (score 0):

For your file manager issue, have you tried uninstalling & reinstalling? To uninstall tap & hold the app icon, this will bring you to the relevant app page, with an uninstall button. I'd consider a reboot between uninstall & reinstall.

Hope this helps,

Jurjen

Comment: Sure, didn't help. I've even wiped the whole phone clean and tried to start from square one --> no luck! Can't install the terminal either, so "sudo apt-get update", which I hoped would work,, is render impossible :-/

Maybe flashing the phone would help, but I think I'd rather refund the thing first

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've redecided and flashed the phone with the newest version of ubuntu touch. Seems to work fine now!

Here's the instructions (german) that I've used: https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Ubuntu_Touch/flash_tool/